# plotting 8th degree polinomial with interpolation and regression

Tags: matlab, regression, interpolation

I am looking for an interpolation for 2nd derivitive of a function with given time and rot relation. 
The problem is when I took the 2nd derivitive of the fitted function my acceleration output is around -5000.
I knew that it is theoretically possible and my polinomial degree might cause this.

I just want to make sure that is there an anything wrong or not.

I will attach my code and the given data.

```
%time data which is x
0
0,00300000000000000
0,00600000000000000
0,00900000000000000
0,0120000000000000
0,0140000000000000
0,0170000000000000
0,0190000000000000
0,0220000000000000
0,0240000000000000
0,0260000000000000
0,0290000000000000
0,0310000000000000
0,0340000000000000
0,0360000000000000
0,0390000000000000
0,0410000000000000
0,0440000000000000
0,0460000000000000
0,0480000000000000
0,0510000000000000
0,0540000000000000
0,0580000000000000
0,0620000000000000
0,0670000000000000
0,0720000000000000
0,0800000000000000
0,0860000000000000
0,0920000000000000
0,0970000000000000
0,102000000000000
0,108000000000000
0,112000000000000
0,117000000000000
0,124000000000000
0,129000000000000
0,134000000000000
0,140000000000000
0,145000000000000
0,151000000000000
0,156000000000000
0,164000000000000
0,171000000000000
0,179000000000000
0,191000000000000
0,201000000000000
0,213000000000000
0,224000000000000
0,235000000000000
0,245000000000000
0,250000000000000

%rot data which is y
0
0,810000000000000
1,24000000000000
1,31000000000000
1,43000000000000
1,48000000000000
1,43000000000000
1,50000000000000
1,41000000000000
1,11000000000000
1,02000000000000
1,03000000000000
1,22000000000000
1,36000000000000
1,34000000000000
1,27000000000000
1,14000000000000
1,11000000000000
1,26000000000000
1,41000000000000
1,15000000000000
1,15000000000000
1,32000000000000
1,59000000000000
2,09000000000000
2,38000000000000
3,54000000000000
4,63000000000000
6,19000000000000
7,03000000000000
7,89000000000000
9,12000000000000
10,0600000000000
11,6900000000000
13,1600000000000
14,0700000000000
15,1400000000000
15,7300000000000
15,9800000000000
16,3700000000000
16,4200000000000
16,7100000000000
16,8500000000000
16,8000000000000
16,1600000000000
15,7300000000000
15,4000000000000
15,1300000000000
14,8500000000000
14,5600000000000
14,2200000000000

directory = 'file\target'
directory = load(directory);
t = directory.time;
r = directory.rot;
degree = 8;
p=polyfit(t,r,degree);
%gives the coeff of the polynomial ordered in des. powers(mention in
%notes)
figure('Name','Section c) fitted data','NumberTitle','off')
plot(t,r,'o',t,polyval(p,t))
xlabel('time'),ylabel('rot'),legend('points','fitted part','Location','northwest','all')
p2 = polyder(polyder(p));
p2 = polyval(p2,t);
figure('Name','Section c) acceleration','NumberTitle','off')
plot(t,r,'o',t,polyval(p2,t))
xlabel('time'),ylabel('rot'),legend('points','fitted part','Location','northwest','all')
```

Wish I could know better way to attach my data but In short it increases slowly with the range of 50. I am pretty new with Polynomial regression so, I would be glad if anyone wants edit my code or answer me.

Comment: Do you need the regression of the data or only its second derivative? You can use your discrete points to evaluate an approximation for the second derivative (check, for instance, [del2](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/del2.html)).

If you actually need the regression of your data, compare it with the numerical second derivative.

Comment: PS: the data you provided uses comma as the decimal separator. MATLAB uses a dot, instead. You should change that in your code.

Comment: You could also check the [spline](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spline.html) function, to approximate your data by a spline. It naturally considers second order derivatives on the approximation. Instead of approximating your function by a 8th degree polynomial, you approximate it with piecewise cubic interpolation.